# Pandas Data frame: Split and shift specific rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

the columns in few rows are concatenated together with delimieter causing data to shift left. How can I split and shift values at the same time. here is an example:

| id | date | account | site | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/21/2022 | JE | 1189 | 40 |
| 2 | 12/21/2022 | PR | 1120 | 60 |
| 3 | 12/21/2022 | JE | 1130 | 90 |
| 4 | 12/31/2022\nJE\n1131 | 60 |  |  |

in line 4, the values for date, account and site are concatenated by new line character {\n}.

How do I split and shift the values to right:

| id | date | account | site | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/21/2022 | JE | 1189 | 40 |
| 2 | 12/21/2022 | PR | 1120 | 60 |
| 3 | 12/21/2022 | JE | 1130 | 90 |
| 4 | 12/31/2022 | JE | 1131 | 60 |

code:

```
lst= [[1,45281,'JE',1189,40],[2,45281,'PR',1120,60],[3,45281,'JE',1130,90],[4,'12/31/2023\nJE\n1131','60']]

columns = ['id','date','account','site','balance']
new = pandas.DataFrame(data = lst, columns = columns)
```

I tried using `new['date'].str.split('\n',expand=True)` but it did not work

Comment: It is probably better to preprocess your data in the original input form, rather than try to do this within Pandas

Comment: Hi @itprorh66. This is actually from a very unstructured source (pdf). There is no way for me to preprocess the data

Comment: Somewhere you gather the data from pdf to a intermediate data structure before building the pandas dataframe.  In your sample you show this as ```lst```.  Preprocess the data structure before going to pandas.

Comment: @Learner27 can we have a more raw form of the data (connected to what itprorh66 said)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I cannot share the actual data here. The source is a PDF. I used Cameleot library in Python to convert it to a DataFrame. Since the PDF looses the table structure, some rows were not clean and this is the closest I got after numerous tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing something like what https://stackoverflow.com/users/14249087/itprorh66 suggests because it is always better to fix data earlier in the process.

For example:

```
lst = [[1, 45281, 'JE', 1189, 40], [2, 45281, 'PR', 1120, 60], [3, 45281, 'JE', 1130, 90], [4, '12/31/2023\nJE\n1131', '60']]
columns = ['id','date','account','site','balance']

tmp_rows = []
for row in lst:
  tmp_row = "\n".join([str(x) for x in row])
  tmp_rows.append(tmp_row)

new2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=[x.split("\n") for x in tmp_rows], columns=columns)
```

```
>>> new2
  id        date account  site balance
0  1       45281      JE  1189      40
1  2       45281      PR  1120      60
2  3       45281      JE  1130      90
3  4  12/31/2023      JE  1131      60
```

But if you do not have the source data and you must operate on the DataFrame you could do something like this to turn the DataFrame into a Series delimited by "\n" and then splitting it again.

```
combined = new.apply(lambda row: "\n".join([str(x) for x in row if not pandas.isna(x)]),axis = 1)
new3 = pandas.DataFrame(data=combined.str.split("\n").tolist(), columns=columns)
```

```
>>> new3
  id        date account    site balance
0  1       45281      JE  1189.0    40.0
1  2       45281      PR  1120.0    60.0
2  3       45281      JE  1130.0    90.0
3  4  12/31/2023      JE    1131      60
```

In both cases you will have to do some more processing to clean up the date format.